# Vim trim whitespace command is deleting percent signs?

Tags: vim

I have been using Vim for years at work (legacy stack), and I recently decided to copy the trim function we use there. It is:

```
fun! TrimWhiteSpace()
    let l:save_cursor = getpos('.')
    %s/\s\+%//e
    call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)
endfun

command! Trim call TrimWhiteSpace()
```

So we just call `:Trim`, and it does it's work. While it works fine at work, at home it is also deleting % signs along with the white space. Example: `printf("Testing %2f", float);` will turn into `printf("Testing 2f", float);`.

The main difference is at work I am on a Unix server, and at home I am on Windows 11. Any idea what is causing this behavior?

P.S. It is possible that this behavior would happen at work too, but in Perl there really is never a situation where there would be white space followed by a %. In C, C++ (what I use at home) obviously there is a lot.

Edit: Let me add my .vimrc for context. It is really bare right now.

```
" GENERAL -------------------------------------------------------

set nocompatible " We are not messing with being vi compatible

set backspace=indent,eol,start " Fix backspace issue

imap <S-BS> <BS>

"filetype on " Enable file type detection

"filetype plugin on " Enable plugins and load plugins for file type

"filetype indent on " Load an indent file for the detected file type

syntax on " Turn syntax highlighting on

set hlsearch " Set highlight search

set showmatch " Show matching words during a search

set showmode " Show mode

set ignorecase " Ignore capital letters during search
set smartcase " But allow for searching by capital specifically

set incsearch " Incrementally highlight matching searches

set tabstop=3 " Set tab width

"set expandtab " Allow spaces instead of tabs

" Enable autocompletion menu after pressing tab
"set wildmenu
"set wildmode=list:longest
"set wildignore=*.docx,*.jpg,*.png,*.gif,*.pyc,*.flv,*.img,*xlsx

fun! TrimWhiteSpace()
    let l:save_cursor = getpos('.')
    %s/\s\+%//e
    call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)
endfun

command! Trim call TrimWhiteSpace()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `substitute` command

```
%s/\s\+%//e
```

matches whitespace `\s`, repeated one or more times `\+`, followed by a literal percent sign `%` and replaces them with nothing, i.e. deleting them.

The following command, on the other hand

```
%s/\s\+$//e
```

matches whitespace `\s`, repeated one or more times `\+`, followed by a line ending `$` and replaces them with nothing.

I think you have a typo in your expression and you actually use the second form at work. Please double check.

See [`:help :substitute`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As) and [`:help pattern`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#pattern).

Comment: You are completely right. I made a typo when transferring the code over. I changed the second % to a $. Thank you very much for the answer and resources linked.

Answer (score 3):

It deletes percent sign, because it is told to do so. The second percent sign in the regex is probably unwanted.

Usually "trimming" stands for deleting spaces at lines' ends. If so then there should be dollar sign instead,

```
%s/\s\+$//e
```

Comment: Funny, when I started typing my answer just five minutes ago I didn't see your answer (which is, of course, correct). It popped out of nowhere when I was just finishing mine. SO says it's been there for 50 minutes. Is it my mind that's malfunctioning or is SO playing tricks here?

Comment: @Friedrich Sometimes pages do not refresh properly.